# Advice needed with Javascript and html form with numerical input & output

Tags: javascript

I am developing a web page for machinists and CNC programmers. There are a lot of formulas for various applications, and I am having trouble finding a way to output my JS code to a form. I am adding the code for one below. Any help would be appreciated, I'm stumped.

```
    <title>Angle depth</title>

</head>
    <body>
      <form id="depth" >
        <p>Angle Tool Depth Calculator</p>
    <div>
        <label for="toolAngleDeg">enter tool angle</label>
            <input name="toolAngleDeg" id="toolAngleDeg" type="text"/> 
     </div>
     <div>
        <label for="finalDia">enter the diameter</label>
            <input name="finalDia" id="finalDia" type="text"/> 
     </div>
     <div> 
         <label for="zDepth">Depth</label>
             <input name="zDepth" id="zDepth"  type="text"/>    
     </div>
     <div>
         <input type="button" id="button01" value="calculate"/>
    </div>
  </form>      
     <script>
          // prompted var           
        var toolAngleDeg = document.getElementById('toolAngleDegree');
            var finalDia = document.getElementById('finalDia');
               // calc var
                   var (toolAngleRad = ((parseFloat('toolAngleDeg') * Math.PI) / 180)) 
                   var (cTool = (.5 / (Math.tan(toolAngleRad / 2))));}
                       var depthZ = Math.round((cTool * parseFloat('finalDia') * 10000) / 10000).toFixed(4);
           //output
                   function getDepth() {
                   document.getElementById("zDepth") = depthZ.value;
               }

         function calcDepth() {
             var button1 = document.getElementById('button01');
                 button01.onclick = getDepth();
         }
             window.onload = calcDepth;
     </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm failing to see the problem. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Put `<span id="some_output"></span>` anywhere in your HTML. Then use `document.getElementById("some_output").innerHTML = myJSVariable;` to display it. (your problem boils down to 1. formatting numbers 2. changing textual content of HTML elements, both things which can easily be googled)

Comment: Actually, forget that. There's lots of other problems with that code.

Comment: Two things: output in an `<input>` makes no sense. See my first comment for a proper solution. And one major problem here is `button01.onclick = getDepth();` which should be `button01.onclick = getDepth;` (the former immediately calls the function, and assigns the returned value to `button01.onclick`. The latter assigns the actual function, not its result.) Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vwnkmukm/

Answer (score 1):

```
var toolAngleDeg = document.getElementById('toolAngleDegree');
```

Your variable `toolAngleDeg` is a DOM element not the value, you will get the value from `toolAngleDeg.value`. Same goes with all other input fields

---

```
parseFloat('toolAngleDeg')
```

Here you are trying to convert the string `'toolAngleDeg'` to a number which will give you `NaN`,  you should pass the variable there instead `parseFloat(toolAngleDeg)`. Same goes with `parseFloat('finalDia')`

---

```
document.getElementById("zDepth") = depthZ.value
```

That should be

```
document.getElementById("zDepth").value = depthZ
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your code, see other answers.
Here is a working solution:

```
<form id="depth">
    <p>Angle Tool Depth Calculator</p>
    <div>
        <label for="toolAngleDeg">enter tool angle</label>
        <input name="toolAngleDeg" id="toolAngleDeg" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="finalDia">enter the diameter</label>
        <input name="finalDia" id="finalDia" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="zDepth">Depth</label>
        <input name="zDepth" id="zDepth" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="button01" onclick="calcDepth()" value="calculate" />
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    function calcDepth() {
        // Save input values in variables         
        var toolAngleDeg = parseFloat(document.getElementById('toolAngleDeg').value);
        var finalDia = parseFloat(document.getElementById('finalDia').value);
        // Calculate depthZ
        var toolAngleRad = (toolAngleDeg * Math.PI) / 180
        var cTool = (.5 / (Math.tan(toolAngleRad / 2)));
        var depthZ = Math.round((cTool * finalDia * 10000) / 10000).toFixed(4);
        // Output depthZ 
        document.getElementById("zDepth").value = depthZ;
    }
</script>
```